# Issue with DatePickerDialog theme

Tags: android, android-datepicker, datepickerdialog

i have a problem with DatePickerDialog it is all white there is no purple like was used to be and something else that i observe is that there is no purple when i choose a textview to enter text or even in the message boxes no colors except for white. I think something happen to theme.
I recently update gradle due to the update on the android studio.
Any suggestions ?

EDIT
i change this from manifest

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
```

to

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.Design.NoActionBar"
```

and it works but with different colors. The colors of this theme are darker and i don't like it at all. Do you know how can i use again AppTheme?

[preview image custom made](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TAcgn.png)

Comment: Do you see the color if you revert gradle and gradle plugin version?

Comment: _"I recently update gradle due to the update on the android studio"_, try to revert that change only, put gradle and android gradle plugin version back to what they were before you updated them and check if you can see the color. If you can, then you'll know that the problem is in the version update. It could help narrowing down the possible cause of your problem.

Comment: if understand right i changed classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1' to         classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0' and i press "sync now" i upload my project but still the same all white ....

Comment: Good, then you know that the problem is not there. You said that it used to work and then it didn't, you should then find what is the change that you made that introduced the issue.

Comment: i change this from manifest android:theme="@style/AppTheme" to android:theme="@style/Theme.Design.NoActionBar"> and it works but with different colors. but why?

Comment: Excellent, now please edit your question and add this new info and also the relevant code